# Car sometimes stalls going from idle accelerating after start

Tags: automatic-transmission, stall, saturn

Saturn ion 2004, 2.2L automatic

Usually it drives perfectly fine, but sometimes after being turned on cold or more usually turned back on after I've been in a shop for maybe 5-30 mins, the car will turn on fine, but when I set it to drive or reverse and press the pedal I can feel it move then stall a little and either continue on fine, or stall out and I have to park and restart the car. No error codes are made by the complete stall out or at all. If I make it past what I'm guessing is 1st gear it doesn't stall again unless I get to 0 mph and try accelerating again.

If it doesn't start and stall out in this way, then it runs well, no stalling, no error lights/codes. I started letting the fuel pump prime for the full 2 seconds after turning the key and that seems to reduce the frequency, esp after I replaced the fuel pump relay, but it just did it to me again yesterday.

I've replaced in the past 6 months the spark plugs, ignition coils, ICM, fuel filter and fuel pump for other reasons, but this is the only issue I randomly have with my car now.

Comment: First thing I would do is clean the throttle body.